# Extract comma separated units from source code using RegEx

Tags: regex, delphi, delphi-10.3-rio

I want to use Regular Expressions to extract information from my source code. Can you help me to build a RegEx that retrieves the units used on the source code ?.

Source code sample:

```
unit ComandesVendes;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, Manteniment;

type
  TFComandesVendes = class(TFManteniment,ActualitzacioFinestra)
    QRCapsaleraNumero: TIntegerField;
    QRCapsaleraData: TDateTimeField;
    QRCapsaleraDataEntrega: TDateTimeField;
...
...
```

I need to get the comma-separated file names since the `uses` clause up to the next `;`. In that sample the output must be:

```
Windows
Messages
SysUtils
Variants
Classes
Graphics
Controls
Forms
Dialogs
Manteniment
```

I'm trying something like

```
^ *uses(\n* *(\w*),)* *\n* *(\w*) *;
```

It matches the uses clause, but it doesn't return each file name separately.

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At [this page](https://www.regular-expressions.info/delphi.html) it says that Delphi uses the PCRE regex flavor.

In that case, one option is to use a capturing group in combination with the `\G` anchor.

```
(?:^ *uses\r?\n *|\G(?!^))(\w+)(?:,\s*|;$)
```

**Explanation**

- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `^ *uses\r?\n *` Match optional spaces from the start of the string, then match and a newline followed by optional spaces again
  - `|` Or
  - `\G(?!^)` Assert the position at the end of the previous match, not at the start (The `\G` anchor matches at 2 positions, either at the start of the string or at the end of the previous match)
- `)` Close non capture group
- `(\w+)` Capture **group 1** Match 1+ word characters
- `(?:,\s*|;$)` Non capture group, match either a comma and 0+ whitespace chars or match `;` at the end of the string.

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/9YyJ72/1)